# Explanation: $H^{-1}$ is the time-scale over which the universe changes by $\mathcal{O}(1)$

Tags: cosmology, time, universe

The Hubble parameter $H$ has dimensions equal to $[T]^{-1}$, and hence there is a natural time-scale for the Universe $H^{-1}$. [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9igHxDHs6Hs) lecture by Neal Weiner says (he wrote at around 4:40)

> $H^{-1}$ is the time-scale over which the universe changes by $\mathcal{O}(1)$.

He also said that unlike cosmologists this is how particle physicists think about the time scale $H^{-1}$.

*Can some explain what does he mean by the statement above?*

Comment: possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/23358/84967, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/18301/84967, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/254744/84967, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/377741/84967, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/10400/84967, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/136056/84967, etc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hubble time, the age of the Universe and expansion rate](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/23358/)

Comment: At least leave a comment before downvoting! It's not constructive at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition, $H = \dot a/a$. In terms of $t_H = H^{-1}$, this reads

$$
a = \dot a\cdot t_H
$$

So if you assumed a fixed expansion rate $\dot a = \text{const}$, the universe would have needed a time $t_H$ to grow to scale $a$.

---

I haven't wached the video, but here's my guess what the lecturer was getting at:

If you do a Taylor-expansion of the scale factor, you end up with
$$
\Delta a = \dot a(t_0)\cdot\Delta t + \mathcal O(\Delta t^2)
$$
If you want that change to be "$\mathcal O(1)$", ie $\Delta a \approx a(t_0)$, you end up with
$$
\Delta t \approx \frac{a(t_0)}{\dot a(t_0)} = H(t_0)^{-1}
$$
This of course assumes the validity of our first order approximation, and I also might be completely wrong about the intended meaning of "changes by $\mathcal O(1)$".

Comment: I have edited the question to clarify what exactly I'm looking for. @Christoph

Comment: @SRS: see edit...